# Bash script to add absolute values of numbers seperated by spaces

Tags: bash, sum, absolute-value

I need a bash script to find the sum of the absolute value of integers separated by spaces. For instance, if the input is:

```
1 2 -3
```

the script should print `6` to standard output
I have:

```
while read x ; do echo $(( ${x// /+} )) ; done
```

which gives me

```
0
```

Without over complicated things, how would I include an absolute value of each x in that statement so the output would be:

```
6
```

Comment: You could remove all `-` characters before converting the spaces to `+`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have almost done it, but the `-`s must have been removed from the line read:

```
while read x; do x=${x//-}; echo $(( ${x// /+} )); done
```

Answer (score 4):

With Barmar's idea:

```
echo "1 2 -3" | tr -d - | tr ' ' '+' | bc -l
```

Output:

```
6
```

Comment: can you show me your example using a variable instead of 1 2 -3 hard coded?

Comment: Replace `1 2 -3` with `$x`.

Answer (score 2):

POSIX friendly implementation without running a loop and without spawning a sub-shell:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env sh

abssum() {
  IFS='-'
  set -- $*
  IFS=' '
  set -- $*
  IFS=+
  printf %d\\n $(($*))
}

abssum 1 2 -3
```

Result:

```
6
```